# return true if tuple has a value?

Tags: sql, database, boolean

say I have a relation with just one tuple, and the attributes are name1 and name2. How can I write a query that would return true whether either name1 or name2 was "joe"? I would have written a sample table but I didn't know how to format one in this post. Thanks.

Comment: Paste in your table, highlight it and `ctl-k` or click the `{}` editor button. This will format it as a code block, indented 4 spaces

Comment: You need to add the database you are working with, and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense without actual data - or rather, there multiple slightly different results that could be obtained depending on the actual *desired* task. Include input and output at the *very least*. (Use code formatting - indent by 4 spaces - and add a prefix `<!--language: lang-none-->` in the markup; if you post *any* data, even that which is ill-formed, others will clean it up for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select CASE when name1 = 'jeo' or name2 = 'jeo' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END from Tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from [tableName] where name1='joe' or name2='joe';
```